# iOS 13.1 (17A844) folder not available on Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode10, xcode11, xcode11.1

**Update: Xcode 11.1 has since been released and resolved this issue, if you need to use 11.0 check the accepted answer.**

After upgrading to iOS 13.1 I am unable to install onto my device with the following error.

`running iOS 13.1 (17A844), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.`

I am aware that I need the 13.1 device support folder however Xcode 11.1 has not been released. I downloaded Xcode 11 from developer/downloads.

Comment: This has been [covered many, many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=running+iOS++which+may+not+be+supported+by+this+version+of+Xcode).

Comment: @rmaddy I agree this is similar to a known and solved problem, however I have found that Xcode 11 does not include the 13.1 folder. I installed Xcode 11 from the developer/downloads page, I cannot confirm if the 13.1 folder is present in the download from the App Store.

Comment: Are you saying the you get the error posted in your question while using Xcode 11? That's weird if you are since I've been using Xcode 11 for quite some time with iOS (iPadOS) 13.1 on my iPad.

Comment: Currently using 10.3, I have 11.0 installed and copied the 13.0 folder which originally worked before upgrading to iOS 13.1. At least on the version of Xcode 11 that I have installed it does not include the 13.1 folder, hoping this helps anyone who also experiences this.

Comment: You don't need the 13.1 folder if you use Xcode 11. But if you want to use 13.1 with Xcode 10.3, then in addition to adding the 13.0 folder to Xcode 10.3, link the 13.0 folder to a 13.1 folder and it should work.

Comment: Yip managed to get it working as per my answer bellow. Thanks for taking the time to reply :)

Comment: But if you have Xcode 11, you don't need to wait for Xcode 11.1 or download anything from some mystery GitHub page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a temporary measure until Xcode 11.1 is released,
this git repository has new and old device support files including 13.1!

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

Xcode 11.1 has since been released which contains the 13.1 folder.

Comment: Why would you download strange files off of the Internet when you can just download Xcode 11?

Comment: I know it doesn't seems to make any sense, but just like me, who doesn't own a device capable of upgrading to OSX 10.14, (so it can't run new xcode), you can still get some extra juice from your old device. (not to build things for production, but to learn and test) This helps when you live in a country where a new mac sometimes costs more than 3 months of your sallary )

Answer (score 7):

```
Xcode 10 -> /Applications/Xcode.app/Show package Contents/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

-> [Download iOS 13.1 here](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport)

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.1.zip
https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport